# Port-Forward for all IPs on an interface

Tags: freebsd, port-forwarding, pf

I'm running a java-based web server as a non-privileged user. Therefore it listens on ports 8080 and 8443 instead of 80 and 443.

Right now I'm using the following `pf` rules to forward the ports internally:

```
rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to $ext_ip port 80 -> $ext_ip port 8080
rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to $ext_ip port 443 -> $ext_ip port 8443
```

(with macros defined for `$ext_if` and `$ext_ip`, obviously)

Now I want to add more IPs to the interface (for SSL vHosts) -- what's the best way, to do this? Do I have to repeat those rules for every IP added? Or can I somehow make a rule for "every IP on that interface"?

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, the IPs are not from the same subnet. I tried listing them in the `$ext_ip` macro, but I still would prefer a solution where I don't have to add every IP explicitly.

Thanks!

Comment: `($ext_if)` will dynamically update to reflect the IP address/addresses of that interface making the `$ext_ip` macro necessary. This is very useful if you're doing NAT and your external IP address is assigned via DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

My research shows that there's no `pf.conf` clause that will get you this level of one-to-one expansion of rules.

I was hoping that you could do this with macros, which in your case would be something like:

```
vhost_ips = "{ 198.51.100.4, 198.51.100.5 }"
rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to $vhost_ips port 80  -> $ext_ip port 8080
rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to $vhost_ips port 443 -> $ext_ip port 8443
```

... but if the macro is used more than once on the same line, it actually expands the latter ones to the entire macro, and invokes round-robin:

```
rdr pass on int0 proto tcp from any to 198.51.100.4 port 80  -> { 198.51.100.4, 198.51.100.5 } port 8080 round-robin
rdr pass on int0 proto tcp from any to 198.51.100.5 port 443 -> { 198.51.100.4, 198.51.100.5 } port 8443 round-robin
```

... which I'm pretty sure was not what you intended. :-)  Tables also appear to be out.  The man page explicitly says:

"Tables can also be used for the redirect address of nat and rdr rules and in the routing options of filter rules, but only for round-robin pools."

So unfortunately, it looks as though your only option is to either manually maintain the list, or generate it as a separate file and include it.

Also unfortunately, the `include` clause is not mentioned in the `pf.conf` man pages on my 7.4, 8.2 or 9.0-RC2 systems, so if you are running the stock PF that comes with FreeBSD, I believe that they are running the PF imported from OpenBSD 4.5, which doesn't appear to support `include` ... but just in case, here's a way to generate the include:

```
$ cat vhost.list
198.51.100.4
198.51.100.5

$ cat gen-vhosts-pf.sh
#!/bin/sh
for ip in `egrep -v ^# /etc/vhost.list`; do
        echo "rdr pass on \$ext_if proto tcp from any to $ip port 80  -> $ip port 8080"
        echo "rdr pass on \$ext_if proto tcp from any to $ip port 443 -> $ip port 8443"
done

$ ./gen-vhosts-pf.sh | sudo tee /etc/pf.conf.vhosts
rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 198.51.100.4 port 80  -> 198.51.100.4 port 8080
rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 198.51.100.4 port 443 -> 198.51.100.4 port 8443
rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 198.51.100.5 port 80  -> 198.51.100.5 port 8080
rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 198.51.100.5 port 443 -> 198.51.100.5 port 8443
```

... which would be imported into pf.conf with:

```
include "/etc/pf.conf.vhosts"
```

If you're not running a PF that supports includes, it'll be a little trickier, but you get the idea.

Sorry for the slightly scattered research; I also couldn't find a canonical way to ask PF for its version information, so had to flail around a bit.

**EDIT:**  You may be able to do the including with the `load anchor` clause, though it appears you will have to repeat your `$ext_if` macro within the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all IPs are on the same subnet, you can use Aggregation

```
$ext_net = "192.168.1.0/24"
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately they're not. I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do anything special as aliases aren't configured as separate networking devices. This is unlike Linux where you have `eth0`, `eth0:1`, `eth0:2` that are treated as discrete interfaces. Consequently, the pf rules should expand to apply to all the IP address present on that interface:

```
# ifconfig sis2 192.168.4.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 alias
# ifconfig sis2
sis2: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        lladdr 00:00:24:c6:4d:ee
        priority: 0
        media: Ethernet autoselect (100baseTX full-duplex)
        status: active
        inet 192.168.1.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::200:24ff:fec6:4dee%sis2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x3
        inet 192.168.4.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.4.255
```

Using the following pf rules...

```
# allow untrusted -> trusted ssh & http traffic
untrust="sis2"
pass in log on $untrust inet proto tcp from $untrust:network to $trust:network port 22
pass in log on $untrust inet proto tcp from $untrust:network to $trust:network port 80
```

And this expands to the following...

```
@32 pass in log on sis2 inet proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.0.0/24 port = ssh flags S/SA
@33 pass in log on sis2 inet proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.0.0/24 port = www flags S/SA
@34 pass in log on sis2 inet proto tcp from 192.168.4.0/24 to 192.168.0.0/24 port = ssh flags S/SA
@35 pass in log on sis2 inet proto tcp from 192.168.4.0/24 to 192.168.0.0/24 port = www flags S/SA
@36 pass in log on sis1 inet proto tcp from 192.168.0.0/24 to 192.168.0.1 port = ssh flags S/SA
```

You will need to reapply your pf rules using `pfctl` but that's about all you have to do to account for aliased IP addresses assuming your macros and rules are correct.

Additionally, you can *ignore* all aliases on an interface in pf by listing it `interface:0`.